# boost bind to a data member callback behavior

Tags: boost, boost-bind, boost-function

Can someone please explain this piece of code?

```
struct Class {
    boost::function<void()> member;
};
Class c;

boost::function<boost::function<void()>()> foo = boost::bind(&Class::member, &c);
boost::function<void()> bar = boost::bind(&Class::member, &c);
```

Why does the definition of `bar` compile and what is the result of it?

Edit: `foo()` works as expected, calling `c.member()`, but `bar()` doesn't.

Comment: Wow. That works? What compiler? I'd think that only `bar` works.

Comment: gcc version 4.4.5, libboost 1.42

Comment: The second is easy, if you assume that the first is correct, since you can always just ignore the return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call is used to "generate" an extractor functor. That functor, when called, will return the member that it was bound to.

The second call just hides the return type of the functor that is passed in (which is the same as in the first example). So essentially, calling `bar` will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to bind if your class was like that:

`class Class {
public:
    void member();
};`

Then  what you want to do is that :

`Class c;`

`boost::function<void()> the_function_i_want_to_call = boost::bind(&Class::member, c);`

`the_function_i_want_to_call.call();`